# Can Existing Public Facing Graphql Service coexist with Graphql Federation

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, federation, apollo-federation

I am currently having a non federated graphql service which is consumed by certain clients, now there is a new requirement where I need to convert my existing non federated graphql service to federated. So my question is can I have two intstance of apollo server running one with federation and another with non federation? I don’t want to maintain two different set of repositories one for federation and another for non federation. Also my existing clients can’t move into federated services anytime soon